# (wx)Maxima: list factors of an integer

Tags: list, maxima, wxmaxima, factoring

How can one return the factors of an integer in a list? *e.g.* `list_factors(6); > [1,2,3,6]`? Is something like this possible? I looked through the documentation but didn't find anything like this tied to "factor" or "prime".

Comment: `ifactors` returns the list of factors with their multiplicities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
listify(divisors(6)); > [1, 2, 3, 6]
```